# Mac Install QT SDK Globally

Tags: macos, qt, macros

I am very new (2 days old) in Mac. I have downloaded QT 5.9 SDK dmg for Mac from QT website. Now when I try to install, it installs everything on my home directory. I want QT SDK to be globally available for all users in my Mac. Also I should be able to compile QT projects from command line from all users. I want QT SDK to be installed in somewhere like `/usr/local` or `/opt/` like it works in Linux. Should I through away the 3.74 GB Qt 5.9 installer and try using `brew` ? or there is some other way out.

Comment: Use Homebrew. Everything will be linked into `/usr/local/{bin,lib}`, and so globally accessible if those are on your `$PATH`.

Comment: But that will not be qt 5.9

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://brewformulas.org/Qt. The Qt installer is not made for a "global" install in a unix sense

Comment: So this will give me all ? QtCreator, linguist, libs and all ?

Comment: @NeelBasu Yes it will be. The latest version available on Homebrew is Qt 5.9.1. And you can install Qt Creator through Homebrew as well, though it's a separate formula, available through the `brew-cask` external command.

Comment: I don't see any `Kits` in Qt Creator. I have installed qt library through `brew install qt` and installed qt creator through `brew cask install qt-creator`

Comment: Thanks it worked